# Difficulty displaying row counts using WebMatrix

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

I have the following code:

```
@helper RetrievePhotoWithName(int userid)
{
    var database = Database.Open("SC");
    var name = database.QuerySingle("select FirstName, LastName, ProfilePicture from UserProfile where UserId = @0", userid);
    var notifications =  database.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NotificationsTable WHERE UserID = @0 AND MessageWasRead = @1", userid, false);

    var DisplayName = "";
    if(notifications < 1)
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + " " + name["LastName"];
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + ", you have " + notifications + " new messages.";
    }
    <a href="@Href("~/Home")" title="My Account"><img src="@Href("~/Shared/Assets/Images/" + name["ProfilePicture"] + ".png")" id="MiniProfilePicture" />&nbsp;@DisplayName</a>

    database.Close();
}
```

which is supposed to count all the rows in my table and either display a "new notifications" message to the user on the web page or just display their name, but it's not working.

Do not edit this question. The reason I am re-posting this question is because my previous one was changed which resulted in inaccurate responses.

Comment: Does `name["FirstName"]` return anything?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what "it's not working" means? There are some smart folks here but we're not mind-readers.

Comment: Yep. It returns my First Name :-)

But it's just the notifications query that is supposed to count number of unread messages, that isn't working.

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand - I am trying to (with the notifiations query) count the number of Unread messages in the MessageWasRead column (which is of *bit* datatype). But it keeps giving me a host of error messages, depending on what I try. Ranging from "cannot convert type dynamic to int" and similar messages

Comment: Check my answer, possibly it would work. Otherwise check @mgnoonan answer.

Comment: Shane, you need to post things like "I tried X, but got error Y; then I tried A and got error B". Otherwise we don't know what problem you're actually having and will not be able to give you useful answers. You should have edited your previous question to include the code rather than create a new one.

Comment: I did. But after having to repost the same question over and over again, you kinda get a little lazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `SELECT COUNT(*)` is returning a single scalar value, I think you want to use `database.QueryValue()` instead:

```
int notifications =  (int)database.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NotificationsTable WHERE UserID = @0 AND MessageWasRead = @1", userid, false);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue(v=vs.99).aspx

Comment: That is what I originally had, @mgnoonan - and it's what I've always used, but today it just didn't work, and I was given different code to try from tutorials online and others on this site, which just led to different errors. But I'll give it a go again, maybe I mis-typed something and didn't realize.

Comment: Post any error messages and we should be able to work it out!

Comment: Sorry, it said "Cannot convert type dynamic to type int"

Comment: QueryValue returns an object, maybe we need to cast it as an int.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
@helper RetrievePhotoWithName(int userid)
{
    var database = Database.Open("SC");
    var name = database.QuerySingle("select FirstName, LastName, ProfilePicture from UserProfile where UserId = @0", userid);
    var notifications =  database.Query("SELECT convert(int,COUNT(*)) as 'counter' FROM NotificationsTable WHERE UserID = @0 AND MessageWasRead = @1", userid, false);

    var DisplayName = "";
    if(notifications["counter"] < 1)
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + " " + name["LastName"];
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + ", you have " + notifications["counter"] + " new messages.";
    }
    <a href="@Href("~/Home")" title="My Account"><img src="@Href("~/Shared/Assets/Images/" + name["ProfilePicture"] + ".png")" id="MiniProfilePicture" />&nbsp;@DisplayName</a>

    database.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1 I was about to write a similar alternative. (Expressions should always have aliases IMHO.)

Comment: Thank you @aF - I pasted that in and received the following error: "Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>'
 
" I don't get it :-/

Comment: It's giving on mine or on @mgnoonan ?

Comment: Thank you @aF. But it gave me this error: "*Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>'*"